# I have a service listening on a port, how do I open the port externally?

Tags: network, security, firewall, tcp

I have a service that is listening on a tcp port, and it is listed with this command:

```
>netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"
tcp4       0      0  192.168.2.5.8070       *.*                    LISTEN          
tcp4       0      0  *.postgresql           *.*                    LISTEN
...and more
```

but it is not accessible from other computers on the same network, and it is not listed with this command:

```
>nmap 192.168.2.5
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

(but e.g. PostgreSQL is listed).

I can access the webserver locally on `http://192.168.2.5:8060` but not from other computers on the same network. How can I open the port externally?

The Firewall on `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall` is **Turned Off**.

Comment: What service is it?

Comment: It is a home made webserver. But I get the same problem with any TCP server I code.

Comment: The usual test would be `telnet 192.168.2.5 8060` what does this show?

Comment: OS X has at least three firewalls; have you checked the other two? `sudo pfctl -sa` will dump the state of "pf" and `sudo ipfw show` will dump the older "ipfw" firewall. See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81421/mac-os-x-server-ignores-remote-http-connections-but-accepts-local-ones) and my answer for some examples of what the output should look like.

Comment: @GordonDavisson care to make that a answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this issue was cased by a network problem. The two computers couldn't reach eachother. So there was no problem with the firewalls or so.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS X greater than 10.8, you should allow incoming connections for this application.

Within:

```
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options…
```

click on the <kbd>+</kbd>, and select the application to use.

Comment: I have `Firewall: Off` `This computer's firewall is currently turned off. All incoming connections to this computer are allowed.` in those preferences.

Comment: → Jonas: thank you for adding this key detail. For me it is actually unimaginable to run any OS without a basic firewall on, logging and checked :[.

Answer (score 0):

If the file `/etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf` exists, then you need to either remove it or edit it so that `ipfw` does not block the traffic. Since `ipfw` is deprecated, probably just delete the file and reboot.